# How to connect html5 app with server

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, html

I am building a very web page that performs some Ajax requests using Jquery and php. JQuery sends a string to php and php answers back with a reposnse. This is working great within the hosting I paid. I want to use the same files to create an Html5 app for Android.

What should I do in order to perform the same Ajax, but now from the App(this is locally in the phone) to php(hosted in my server) and vice versa?
In case it helps, I used siteground for my hosting. I would like to have a good and proper approach to launch the App into production; not workarounds.

The app ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'ajaxphp.php', 
            data: { sentvar: "hello" },
            success: function(response) {
                $("#responseecho").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The php

```
$x = $_POST['sentvar'];    
if ($x == "hello")
    echo "variable received";
else
    echo "variable not received";
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping it the same? What happens?

Comment: I tried, but got an No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. I thought that this approach is not allowed if the JS script is not hosted in server.

Comment: Add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to the top of your `php` page and try again?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I could test it right now. Including the header made it work great. Thanks!

Comment: I've added it as an answer with more information, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a header to allow access from any origin to the PHP file with:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Make sure it's before any output (including whitespace) or it'll throw an error.

---

Alternatively, you can make the same change in your `.htaccess` file by adding:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Of course, you'll need the `mod_headers` mod enabled for this to work, but it'll apply across all files influenced by `.htaccess`. To limit this to certain filetypes (such as `.php`), you can modify it like so:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```